# Stack Overflow Bugged in Internet Explorer 10

Tags: bug, status-completed, internet-explorer-10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [After improved a suggested-edit, you are redirected to the question, not back to review tasks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144283/after-improved-a-suggested-edit-you-are-redirected-to-the-question-not-back-to)

I'm running into some pretty nasty site-breaking issues with Internet Explorer 10 and Stack Overflow.

- While reviewing edits, I opted to "Improve" an edit.  After making my changes and clicking "Save Edit", I was first prompted that I had an edit in progress, and did I want to "Stay on the page" or "Leave the page".  When I chose to leave the page, I given an error message by Stack Overflow that `user xxxxx has already edited this post`, where `xxxxx` was the user who suggested the edit that I was improving.  Then, opting to save the edit again, I'm presented with spam protection because I was too quick on the "edits".
- While editing a post I found on my own, another user edited and saved the post before I finished.  I was given the message that "an edit has been made to this post", much as I would expect to see if I were just looking at the post.  When I clicked the message, the edit textarea was gone and the edited post was shown.  After trying to reload or navigate away, I was presented with a dialog that an edit was in progress, and did I want to stay on the page or leave the page.

Comment: Yes, just before few minutes, i saw this on google chrome. First i thought it was my slow connection problem.

Comment: possibly Related [After improved a suggested-edit, you are redirected to the question, not back to review tasks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144283)

Comment: These seem annoying, but hardly "site-breaking." Are they happening for you _only_ with IE 10, or is that just the only browser you tried?

Comment: @Popular I'd consider losing an edit with no way of retrieving it as site-breaking, yes.  As for reproducibility, I only just noticed it under IE10.  Under Chrome, I do see the "Leave this page" prompt when saving an edit via improving a post, but I was not informed that an edit had already been made by the user who originally suggested the edit and asked to confirm writing over a newer edit.  To really test the second point, I'd need to find a post that someone else could edit while I was editing, which would require some coordination, unless I get lucky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug in the improve / edit code that we found and killed related to improving a suggested edit.  Let us know if you continue to have issues.